# PHP image output issue

Tags: php, image, header, export

I have a problem with generating and exporting image with PHP.

So I have this:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=WHATEVER.jpg');
$dragon = self::static_dragon($numbers,$avatars,$new_name,$filepath);
```

Inside of static_dragon function I load data from database, work with them, etc and then:

```
imagejpeg($canvas,'',60);
imagedestroy($canvas); 
return true;
```

What I want to achieve is that if I write `<img src="http://www.example.com/dragon.php&width=100&height=100" />` it will give me the image. Everything works fine, database connection, even saving the final jpg file on server, only problem is that browser doesn't show me the image. I think maybe some problem in headers? Incidentally, I cannot execute the headers after the function as script tells me that headers were already sent (even though I don't see any command which would do so).

Comment: do you echo anything out before you set the headers? even if it's only whitespace before your `<?php` or anything?

Comment: No, nothing, the "header already sent" error i telling me that headers were sent on line: $handler = imagecreatefromjpeg($picture); which makes no sense to me

Comment: Have you checked that there are no error or warning messages being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are u doing the same:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=WHATEVER.jpg');

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('download.jpg') or  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream'); // this will let u know whether the creation of image resource was a failure

imagestring($im, 3, 40, 20, 'GD Library', 0xFFBA00); //just a add on 

imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($canvas);
return true;
```

The above code is working fine in a browser. Any errors?

@Tom as you have mentioned u get error: "header already sent" for imagecreatefromjpeg. Solve  the error first as imagecreatefromjpeg() provides the resource for the image. If the resource is failing then image wont be visible.

Give a try by using, @imagecreatefromjpeg()

Comment: Ah now im thinking about it, yes it did give me error with image resource and that might be the "already sent error". What is difference from imagecreatefromjpeg() and @imagecreatefromjpeg() ? I will try without the error, what is the function imagestring() ? Thank you!

Comment: Ok so now i can have the headers where I want, but image is still not displaying. In Chrome its just broken image, in Firefox I see message: The image "http://domain.com/?request=request&width=300&height=300" cannot be displayed because it contains errors. Any more advice? Thank you

Comment: Having the @ operaton in front of a function will prevent printing error messages to the user’s browser.I hv updated the code with handler.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you forgotten to add

```
 echo $dragon
```

object in the content of the php file? :)
add this line to the end of your php file:

```
echo $dragon
```

[see](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_an_image_stored_in_a_database__PHP_-16637.html)

Comment: I thought the same, but that didnt help as well

Answer (score 1):

So instead of echo-ing $canvas use this:

`$this->getResponse()->setContent($canvas)`

in the head part of your php file.

(I assumed that $canvas is the object loaded from DB)

Please make sure that you have not printed any other thing in the php file.